# Preventing DOMSubtreeModified event in Chrome from firing with every change in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

everyone. There's an issue with Chrome (I don't know if it happens with other browsers as well). The situation is with a website that is a few years old. Was developped with standard JavaScript, not jQuery. There are thousands of codelines, so updating it now is not an option.

The thing is, this reads data from a database at the server, which returns some times 10 rows, some times over 500. That is the normal operation. In any case, the request is done via simple AJAX, and it returns an XML. The database responds in less than a second, the formatting of the XML is also in a second, maybe two on a slow day. But when JavaScript receives it back, that's the problem. With 10 elements in the XML there's no problem, but when it's 500, I want to kill myself.

After days of debugging and trying to find the problem, I finally did, but don't know how to fix it. The problem is that when the XML returns, every element is displayed in a simple `<table>`, meaning every node is basically a `<tr>` and every node's child is a `<td>` and `<input type="text">`. In the end, no matter how many rows it has, the table has 7 columns.

So here's an example of what it does. It simply goes through the nodes and creates the rows and cells with their input fields:

```
var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
for (var i = 0; i < theXML.childNodes.length; i++)
{
   var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
   row.style.backgroundColor = "Red";

   for (var j = 0; j < theXML.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++)
   {
       var cell = row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
       cell.width = "200px";
       cell.className = "cellClass";

       var d = document.createElement("input")
       d.type = "text";
       d.width = "190px";
       cell.appendChild(d);
   }
}
```

**Now, the problem**

The code does what it's supposed to do, the table is created with the right rows, columns and inputs, but each and every single time it goes through a width, appendChild, className or other attribute setting, Chrome calls a `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which is first defined in the `Startup()` function in the content.js file (not part of my project, so it most be Chrome's). The event calls a `onDomChange` function which receives `document` as parameter, which only calls `updateDocumentListeners` and sends it the parameter, which calls `updateInputListeners`, which goes through EVERY SINGLE INPUT in the document using a `for()`, just to call `updateInputListeners`, which only return true or false depending on some conditions.

Now, when there are only 10 rows, that means that in the end we'll have 70 inputs, which in turn means that by the end it would have called the `onDomChange` several times, that is: 70 + 69 + 68 + ...., because it goes through everything that's been added before. And that was to be also multiplied by every single attribute you set.

In other words, with every input created, it calls `onDomChange`. On every attribute I set, it calls `onDomChange`. If I add a second input, it goes twice, once for the element and/or the attribute I'm setting and another for the previous one. Here's what it does:

```
//This is the code I found while debugging
function updateDocumentListeners(document)
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
        updateInputListeners(inputs[i]);
}
```

With 500 inputs, meaning also 500 cells, it simply won't end. Oh, and if there are already other inputs (including types hidden, radio, etc), they are included in the cycle. And then Chrome has the audacity to send a message with an option telling me that it's taking too long and prompts for whether I want to wait or cancel.

**What I've tried**

Since it all happens because of the event, I've tried to remove it, process the table and then reinstate it, but I can't remove it, because it's declared like this in content.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){ onDomChangeNoThrow(document); }, true);
```

This means I can't use removeEventListener, because it is defined as an anonymous function. I've already tried it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow! 13 views and no answer in 6 days. Alright, I know I'm saying with this question that either Google made a mistake in Chrome or it actually turns out that no one dares to admit that what Chrome does is wrong. I would understand calling the event at the end of the developer's Javascript code, but not every single time JS changes the width or colour properties. At the very least, that is what JS is for. ¿What's the point in that, firing a DOM change event with changes such as those?

Comment: 2 months, 57 views, not even a hint of a possible answer. Ok, no problem. I know what some are going to say, that it's been months and I haven't found a solution yet, meaning I'm lazy or something like that. That's life being an anonymous avatar these days. Well, thanks to those who actually read this and even tried to find a solution. Any thought would have been appreciated, though.